# Are there any localized constants like "Today", "Tomorrow", "Yesterday" etc in Joda or Java Date and time API?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have to implement the functionality which enables the website customer to see the nearest possible day of delivery. A couple of examples:

> Delivery available Today, June 20
>
> Delivery available Tomorrow, June 21
>
> Delivery available Tuesday, June 24

The problem is that this property is localized in 6 different languages and I would like to know if there is a way not to create localized properties for time adverbs like "Today" and "Tomorrow"? Maybe there are any predefined constants or enums?

Comment: Have you tried searching [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+get+yesterday&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS846US846&oq=java+get+yesterday) or the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)? Or even [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+get+yesterday%27s+date) itself?

Comment: I don’t think you’re the only guy needing this stuff around the World.

Comment: So this isn't a question about date handling but about translation/localisation of some date related words?

Comment: @Zephyr, you didn't understand the question. I need localized constants for words like "today" or "tomorrow"

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, yes! You are the only person who understood the question correctly :)

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question and clarify what you are asking for then. As written, it is not very clear exactly what you're asking for.

Comment: As far as I know, nothing like this exists in Java SE.  You can easily implement it with a [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ResourceBundle.html), though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, neither standard Java nor Joda-Time have such features.

However, my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) supports relative expressions like "today", "tomorrow", "yesterday" or "next Sunday" in 90+ languages. Example using a test clock:

```
  TimeSource<?> clock = () -> PlainTimestamp.of(2015, 8, 1, 10, 24, 5).atUTC();
  String durationInDays =
      PrettyTime.of(Locale.GERMAN).withReferenceClock(clock).printRelative(
          PlainTimestamp.of(2015, 8, 1, 17, 0).atUTC(),
          Timezone.of(EUROPE.BERLIN),
          TimeUnit.DAYS);
  System.out.println(durationInDays); // heute (german word for today)
```

You can also get the single translations for those expressions by calling methods like 
[PrettyTime.of(Locale.getDefault()).printToday()](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PrettyTime.html#printToday--) or `printNext(Weekday)` etc. If you are on Android you can use the sister Project Time4A. A list of supported languages is also [documented](http://time4j.net/tutorial/i18n.html#x2). If you miss a language then please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [`getDisplayName` method of Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getDisplayName-int-int-java.util.Locale-); it returns a localized string of your needed attribute.

This is how you can get a string of the attribute you need.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
String <attribute_localized> = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.<attribute>, Calendar.LONG, Locale.<your_locale>);
```

Note, however, that the method will return `null` for any numeric value; in that case you have to use the method `get(Calendar.<attribute>)`

Here is an example of this code working:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

Locale myLocale = Locale.ENGLISH;
Integer year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
Integer day_of_month = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

String month = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, myLocale);
System.out.println("Today is " + day_of_month + " " + month + " " + year);
// Today is 20 June 2019

myLocale = Locale.ITALIAN;
month = cal.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, myLocale);
System.out.println("Today is " + day_of_month + " " + month + " " + year);
// Today is 20 giugno 2019
```

Comment: If you need also words like "today" translated, I _don't think_ there are any keywords like that in Calendar; probably the best approach is to localize the string in all the languages you need

Comment: This does not address the question.  And a localized DateFormat or DateFormatter will do the job better.