# Are there any localized constants like "Today", "Tomorrow", "Yesterday" etc in .net framework

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have to implement the functionality which enables the website customer to see the nearest possible day of delivery. A couple of examples:

> Delivery available Today, June 20
>
> Delivery available Tomorrow, June 21
>
> Delivery available Tuesday, June 24

The problem is that this property is localized in 6 different languages and I would like to know if there is a way not to create localized properties for time adverbs like "Today" and "Tomorrow"? Maybe there are any predefined constants or enums?

(This is a duplicate to [Java Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56686233/are-there-any-localized-constants-like-today-tomorrow-yesterday-etc-in-j) but for the .net framework)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer). It supports generation of human readable contextual strings (like *tomorrow*) for datetime instances, and is localizable.

```
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-30).Humanize()     =>     yesterday
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-2).Humanize()     =>     2 hours ago
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(30).Humanize(     =>     tomorrow
    DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2).Humanize()     =>     2 hours from now
```

Examples above from Fiddle demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sKea7c